# Prove that if $A$ is a $2\times 2$ projection matrix and $B$ is similar to $A$ then $B$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Suppose $A$ is a $2\times 2$ projection matrix and $B$ is similar to
>   $A$ then $B$ is normal.

$\underline {\mbox {This is what I have so far}}$:

From the fact that $A$ is $2\times 2$ projection matrix we know that $A$ is **unitary diagonalizable over** $\pmb {\mathbb R}$. We also know that every projection matrix is similar to the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ .That is, there exist real unitary $P$ and diagonal $D$ such that :

$$ P^*AP=D \ \ \ \mbox{where D is similar to} \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

We also know that $B$ is similar to $A$, that is there exists invertible $Q$ such that :

$$Q^{-1}BQ=A \implies B=QAQ^{-1}$$

From this I can only derive that $B$ is diagonalizable, but how can I also derive that $B$ is normal?

Comment: The statement is false. There is no way you can prove it.

Comment: Why? Can you elaborate? Do you have a counter-example?

Comment: Consider $A=\pmatrix{1\\ &0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&0}$.

Comment: Your statement implies that every projection matrix is normal, which is definitely false.

Comment: Did you find a $Q$ matrix such that $Q^{-1}BQ=A$? I'm trying to do it by finding the eigenvectors of $B$ and I get a singular matrix $Q$.

Comment: I don't have time to do the calculations, but $B$ is a matrix with distinct eigenvalues, so its Jordan form is $A$ and it is similar to $A$. Alternatively, you may consider the example $A=B=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&0}$. Here $A$ is definitely similar to itself (which is $B$), and $A$ is a projection matrix ($A^2=A$), but $A=B$ is not normal.